# HTML markup within a Component JSX attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm unsure of some of the terminology for React elements so please excuse me if I'm off the mark.

**My Issue**

I've set up this component in my React web app.

```
const Title = ({lineContent}) => {

  let line1 = useRef(null);

  return (
    <h1 className="page-title">
      <div ref={el => line1 = el} className="line">
        {lineContent}
      </div>
    </h1>
  )
  
  };
```

and I'm pulling it through to a parent component:

```
<Title lineContent="Text for line one"/>
```

I want to wrap a `<span>` around a word within the `lineContent=""` attribute, so I can change it's colour.

```
<Title lineContent="Text for <span>line</span> one"/>
```

But it currently renders out the `<span>` tag as if it was standard text.

Is there any way of setting this up so that the `<span>` is recognised as HTML so I can style it in css? Any direction would be great appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just pass the element it self instead of a string:

```
<Title
  lineContent={
    <>
      Text for <span>line</span> one
    </>
  }
/>
```